# How to format dataframe to look like this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks something like this

```
A   B    C
x   xy   6
x   xz   7
x   xa   12
y   ya   2
y   yb   45
z   zc   4
```

I would like to reorganize it, so that it gives me the totals for A, and then gives me the biggest within A, for example:

```
A   B    C    D
x   25   xa   12
y   47   yb   45
z   4    zc   4
```

Essentially, what this did was take the totals by group in A, and puts that in B.. it finds the biggest entity within A and puts that to C with the number of the entity in D.

How could I organize a dataframe to perform this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way to put it

```
df.set_index('B').groupby('A').C.agg(['sum', 'idxmax', 'max'])

   sum idxmax  max
A                 
x   25     xa   12
y   47     yb   45
z    4     zc    4
```

If you want to rename columns to be `'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'`

```
df.set_index('B').groupby('A').C.agg(['sum', 'idxmax', 'max']) \
    .rename(columns=dict(sum='B', idxmax='C', max='D')).reset_index()

   A   B   C   D
0  x  25  xa  12
1  y  47  yb  45
2  z   4  zc   4
```

Comment: Nice solution, don't need to reset_index() though to get desired output. +1, or well this is arguable

Comment: It's unclear if OP wanted `A` as index or column.  I provided enough information for OP to decide.  Thanks for the compliment.

Comment: Thank you @piRSquared. Much appreciated +1.

Comment: Hi piR, for rename `df.set_index('B').groupby('A').C.agg({'B':'sum', 'C':'idxmax', 'D':'max'})`

Comment: So basically two rows (for readability - my fav): **aggs = dict(B='sum',C='idxmax',D='max')** and 
**df.set_index('B').groupby('A')['C'].agg(aggs)**

Comment: @Wen and Anton vBR, passing these kind of dicts to `agg` will be deprecated in the future.  Run this option with an upgraded pandas version to see warning.

Comment: @piRSquared I am trying to implement your solution.... How would I do this if say, my column header for C is actually named: This Week? `df.set_index('House').groupby('Bank Name').This Week.agg(['sum', 'idxmax', 'max'])` - this will obviously give me an error.. can I write `('This Week')` instead?

Comment: You were close!  `df.set_index('House').groupby('Bank Name')['This Week'].agg(['sum', 'idxmax', 'max'])`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
s = df.groupby('A')['C'].sum().rename('B')
df = df.loc[df.groupby('A')['C'].idxmax()].rename(columns={'B':'C','C':'D'})
df = df.join(s, on='A').sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
   A   B   C   D
2  x  25  xa  12
4  y  47  yb  45
5  z   4  zc   4
```